# What did the Hobbits call the story we know as The Lord of the Rings?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

I came across a jarring statement in *Unfinished Tales*, in the chapter "*The Palantíri*":

> It must however be noted with regard to the narrative of *The Lord of the Rings* that over and above such deputed authority, even hereditary, any "Heir of Elendil" (that is, a recognized descendant occupying a throne or lordship in the Númenórean realms by virtue of this descent) had the *right* to use any of the *palantíri*.

This passage seems to occur "in-universe", which is why it surprised me.  I don't recall coming across a reference to *The Lord of the Rings* as such in Tolkien's other works, in an in-universe context.  I was also under the impression that Frodo's title for the story we know as *The Lord of the Rings* in *The Red Book of Westmarch* was considerably more wordy, something like *The Downfall of the Lord of the Rings and the Return of the King*.

Would Frodo, Bilbo, or Sam have called the story *The Lord of the Rings*?  If not, did Tolkien simply make a mistake here?

Comment: The Lord of the Rings is mentioned at the Counsel of Elrond. "Sooner or later, The Lord of The Rings would learn of its hiding place and bend all his power towards it".

Comment: @CarlSixsmith - Good point.  I know that Sauron is referred to as "the Lord of the Rings" on occasion, but I don't remember the story itself being referred to as such.

Comment: Unfinished tales is heavily out of universe IIRC. It quite literally is the bits that weren't quite finished

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - I'm almost done with the book, and I don't think any of the main text was out-of-universe.  It is called *Unfinished Tales* because Tolkien hadn't edited and revised it a billion times, as he was wont to do.  It doesn't include any stories that end mid-sentence, for instance.  It just wasn't ready to be published (by Tolkien's exacting standards, at least) when he died.  I think the biggest problem he had with the stories was that he hadn't been able to make them completely consistent with the already published works.

Comment: My thinking on this, as the question asks for what the Hobbits called the story, is "The story of Nine-fingered Frodo and the ring of Doom". Exactly as Sam (a Hobbit) says in the book

Comment: [Synechdoche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The story is titled ([in-universe](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WZ0f_yUgc0UC&pg=PA1004&lpg=PA1004&dq=%22from%20his%20own%20observations%20and%20the%20accounts%20of%20his%20friends%22&source=bl&ots=qr7mJWchTn&sig=8YKFZDfWlQHcj2SzmvUEVEklmHs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCUQ6AEwA2oVChMI8-b3t-uMxwIVifMeCh2NRgBs#v=onepage&q=%22from%20his%20own%20observations%20and%20the%20accounts%20of%20his%20friends%22&f=false)) as:

[image]

[image]

---

> <s>My Diary.</s> <s>My Unexpected Journey.</s> <s>There and Back Again. And
> What Happened After.</s>
> <s>Adventures of Five Hobbits.</s> <s>The Tale of the Great Ring, compiled by Bilbo Baggins from his own observations and the accounts of his friends.</s> <s>What we did in the War of the Ring.</s>
>
> **THE DOWNFALL
>
>                                                                               OF THE
>
>                                                                   LORD OF THE RINGS
>
>                                                                             AND THE
>
>                                                                   RETURN OF THE KING**
>
> <sub>*(as seen by the Little People; being the memoirs of Bilbo and
> Frodo of the Shire, supplemented by
>                                                   the accounts of their friends
> and the learning of the Wise.)*</sub>
>
> <sub>*Together with extracts from Books of Lore translated by Bilbo
> in Rivendell.*</sub>

It seems at least reasonably likely that they would shorten the name of the story to ***"The Lord of the Rings"*** since that's a pretty catchy title (as evidenced by the fact that at least one other author (Tolkien) calls it that).

Comment: How about *"That Awful Affair of Mad Baggins and his Poor Nephew Who Went Off for a Year with Master Gamgee and Came Back a Broken Hobbit, Not to Mention the Other Two Who Were a Bit Peculiar Afterward"*?

Comment: @Beta - "*The year when horrible people turned up asking lotsa questions about Frodo, then turned our shire into crap*"

Comment: Where in the books is this title (with its revisions) given?

Comment: Wow. This answer looks *awful* on mobile

Comment: @raidri - Page 1002 of the ebook version https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WZ0f_yUgc0UC&pg=PA1004&lpg=PA1004&dq=%22from+his+own+observations+and+the+accounts+of+his+friends%22&source=bl&ots=qr7mJWchTn&sig=8YKFZDfWlQHcj2SzmvUEVEklmHs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCUQ6AEwA2oVChMI8-b3t-uMxwIVifMeCh2NRgBs#v=onepage&q=%22from%20his%20own%20observations%20and%20the%20accounts%20of%20his%20friends%22&f=false

Comment: Although we don't know enough genuine Hobbitish to translate.

Comment: @Gae.S. - SE changed the formatting rules. It all worked beautifully before...

Answer (score 37):

Richard has correctly identified the in-universe title of the story. However, that has nothing to do with the reason that *Lord of the Rings* is referred to by that name in the "Palantíri" essay. Christopher Tolkien explains the source of this essay in the introduction to *Unfinished Tales*:

> For the second edition of *The Lord of the Rings* (1966) my father made substantial emendations to a passage in *The Two Towers*,  III 11 "The Palantír" (three-volume hardback edition p. 203), and some others in the same connection in *The Return of the King*, V 7 "The Pyre of Denethor" (edition cited p. 132), though these emendations were not incorporated in the text until the second impression of the revised edition (1967). **This section of the book is derived from writings on the *palantíri* associated with this revision; I have done no more than assemble them into a continuous essay**.

(emphasis added)

In other words, this is not a slip on Tolkien's part; he's writing this essay as the author, to try and clarify his thoughts on a section of his book.

The book itself, or at any rate the manuscript conceived of as being the basis of the novel, is referred to by name only once by any character. As Frodo is consoling Sam at the Grey Havens, he tells Sam:

> You will be the Mayor, of course, as long as you want to be, and the most famous gardener in history; and **you will read things out of the Red Book**, and keep alive the memory of the age that is gone...

That's the only reference to the book,  by name, by a character in the book.

Comment: Very interesting.  Thanks!  I didn't think my copies of the LotR books were substantially revised from the original version.  I guess I was wrong about that.

Comment: Is there any indication of the use of the name in-universe?

Comment: @Richard the book is only ever referred to as "the Red Book" in-universe.

Comment: @wadCheber see my update.

Comment: Elsewhere, the book is referred to as The Red Book of Westmarch, as it was kept in Westmarch later in the history.

Comment: there are multiple times the book is referred to, it may be the only time it is named but the book is referenced by the characters in several places.

Comment: @CarlSixsmith Oops.  Right you are. I had thought I included "by name" in there.