# What happened to The Hobbit and The Lord of the Rings as the text that existed in Middle-Earth?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

Excuse me for not having read the books, I just rewatched the movies while beginning *The Silmarillion*, with *The Hobbit* and *The Lord of the Rings* to follow.

At the end of *Return of the King* as he leaves for Valinor Frodo gives the book containing *The Hobbit* and *The Lord of the Rings* to Sam, saying something along the lines of "the last pages are for [him] to fill."

Do we know what becomes of that book? Did it stay in the Shire, or follow Sam to Valinor? Was it reproduced to be held in the libraries of Elves and Men? Obviously, some of the stories would travel as news of the land, but what of the book itself?

Comment: In the Third Age, that of men, the books were published. Rumour of them grew and eventually a new hero emerged - Peter Jackson, who battled the forces of dark film execs 'till he was finally victorious and was able to bring the feature films to the world.

Comment: @A.Steer Uh, wow, it does entirely, and the next question I was going to ask, which was "Does The Silmarillion exist as a text within Middle-Earth?"

Well, those powers that be, feel free to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102630/how-did-j-r-r-tolkien-learn-about-the-events-of-his-books-in-universe https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97142/what-did-the-hobbits-call-the-story-we-know-as-the-lord-of-the-rings https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/179896/was-the-hobbit-meant-to-be-an-adaptation-of-there-and-back-again-by-bilbo

Comment: Yes, "original version" of Silmarillion was also part of the Red Book.